# How to change the generated XML's encoding style and name space?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to creat an XML in this form:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CastleConfigTop xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd/c5c.xsd" Format="1">
  <ProjectInfo ProjectCode="1" ProjectIdentifier="C5_Valeo_SL">
    <ProjectName>TheProjectName</ProjectName>
  </ProjectInfo>
  <Options />
  <ConfigFile Name="C5_Valeo_SL">
    <History>
     
    </History>
    <Includes>
      
    </Includes>
    <Options>
      
    </Options>
    <DataTypes>
      <Options>
        <options />
      </Options>
      <ArgTypes />
      <Enums />
      <Lookups />
      <Doc />
    </DataTypes>
    <Interfaces />
    <Modules>
      
    </Modules>
  
    <ExexutionUnits />
    <Doc></Doc>
  </ConfigFile>
</CastleConfigTop>
```

And im using this code, where the object ccTop contains all the necessary classes:

```
 public void saveXmlPath()
     {
           //xmldoc.Save(this.OutputPath+"\\"+projectName+".C5C");
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CastleConfigTop));
         string outpath = this.OutputPath + "\\" + projectName + ".C5C";
         using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@outpath))
         {
             serializer.Serialize(writer, ccTop);
         }


     }
```

But the output XMl has the encoding style "utf-8" (lower case) and a different namespace like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CastleConfigTop xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ProjectInfo ProjectCode="1" ProjectIdentifier="C5_Valeo_SL">
    <ProjectName> ProjectName </ProjectName>
  </ProjectInfo>
  <Options />
  <ConfigFile Name="C5_Valeo_SL">
    <History>  
    </History>
    <Includes> 
    </Includes>
    <Options>  
    </Options>
    <DataTypes>
      <Options />
      <ArgTypes />
      <Enums />
      <Lookups />
      <Doc />
    </DataTypes>
    <Interfaces />
    <Modules> 
    </Modules>
    <Difs>  
    </Difs>
    <ExexutionUnits />
    <Doc>SAS Volvo SPA</Doc>
  </ConfigFile>
</CastleConfigTop>
```

Any Idea about how to make them exactly similar?

Comment: Is there any reason why?  Semantically, these are pretty much the same.  The additional namespace declaration doesn't do anything and the casing of the encoding isn't important.  Is it actually causing a problem?

Comment: I know it doesn't make a difference but the generated xml file is sent to another end (a company) which reads the xml file this way i suppose.

Comment: If you want it identical you'll probably have to post-process this after it's generated.  `XmlSerializer` isn't quite as flexible as you need.  You seem to be missing the `Format` attribute (add this to your `CastleConfigTop`) and you may or may not be able to add your `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute this way too.

Comment: Is there a way I can read the file after I generate it and edit these first two lines? Because they are the same in all the XML documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post-process this using LINQ to XML to get what you want.

Create an `XDocument` and serialize your object to this:

```
var doc = new XDocument();

using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, ccTop);
}
```

Then modify the declaration and attributes:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

doc.Root.Attributes()
    .Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration && a.Value == "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
    .Remove();

doc.Root.Add(new XAttribute(xsi + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "xsd/c5c.xsd"));
doc.Root.Add(new XAttribute("Format", 1));
```

And then write to disc.  Note you can use `XmlWriterSettings` to set various options for writing, such as indentation.

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true
};

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings))
{
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Or if you can just use `Save` (which gives you less options, but the defaults should be fine):

```
doc.Save(FILENAME);
```

I wouldn't expect the declaration to be an issue in lower case, but if it is you'll have to modify this using some other means - `XmlWriter` takes an `Encoding` and will convert this internally to the lowercase form, so changing this in the `XDocument` won't help.

Comment: This works but the whole xml is generated in one line...Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need to tell the `XmlWriter` to indent the output - I've updated the answer.  Alternatively, `doc.Save(FILENAME)` will do what you want.

Comment: This did the namespace part correct but the encoding is still lower case.Thanks alot though.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned this isn't easily modifiable using the XML APIs - it uses the `Encoding.WebName` internally, which is lowercase.  I'd confirm this is an issue before deciding to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outpath , true, Encoding.ASCII);
```

You can have a try with these code

Comment: And writing in ASCII helps... how?  The output is required to be UTF-8.

Comment: This changed the encoding style to ASCII and ofcourse it did nothing with the namespace part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            saveXmlPath();
        }
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void saveXmlPath()
        {
            CastleConfigTop ccTop = new CastleConfigTop();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CastleConfigTop));
           XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("xsi","xsd/c5c.xsd");
            ns.Add("", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, ccTop, ns);
            }


        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CastleConfigTop", Namespace = "xsi")]
    public class CastleConfigTop
    {
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This sets the wrong `xsi` namespace, the wrong default namespace, and uses the wrong namespace for `CastaleConfigTop`.  What you'll get is `<q1:CastleConfigTop xmlns:xsi="xsd/c5c.xsd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q1="xsi" />`.

Comment: Charles is right .And the "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" was added inside the includes tag. Also i need the whole line xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd/c5c.xsd" Format="1"> to be added next to "castleconfigTop"